# I have been experiencing this error while building release for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':screen:verifyReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:168: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:169: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:170: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:171: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:172: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
> error: failed linking references.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     425.8s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
mitto@Titos-MacBook-Pro solutech-sat % flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                                             Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1194KB to 1134KB: Removed 5%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':screen:verifyReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:168: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projects/Solutech/apps/solutech-sat/build/screen/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:169: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
> /Users/mitto/Projec

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate bundles instead of apk.

```
flutter build appbundle
```

check this doc : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle